# how to retrieve the different original frequency in each FFT caculating and without any frequency leakage in java

Tags: java, audio, fft, frequency, javasound

I'm fighting for such question as recovering the original frequency from audio data recorded by mic.

Sorry for my english...

Let me explain this question more clearly. I have generated some specific frequency using the following code I:

```
void genTone() {
    numSamples = (int)(0.2 * sampleRate);   //duration * sampleRate;
    sample = new double[numSamples];
    generatedSnd = new byte[2 * numSamples];

    // fill out the array
    for (int i = 0; i < numSamples; ++i) {
        sample[i] = Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * i / (sampleRate/freqOfTone));
    }

    // convert to 16 bit pcm sound array
    // assumes the sample buffer is normalised.
    int idx = 0;
    for (final double dVal : sample) {
        // scale to maximum amplitude
        final short val = (short) ((dVal * 32767));
        // in 16 bit wav PCM, first byte is the low order byte
        generatedSnd[idx++] = (byte) (val & 0x00ff);
        generatedSnd[idx++] = (byte) ((val & 0xff00) >>> 8);
    }
}
```

And I have recored the sound using the following code II:

```
private void recordInBackground() {
    int read = 0;
    while (isRecording) {
        short data[] = new short[bufferSize];   // bufferSize = 4096

        read = audioRecorder.read(data, 0, bufferSize);
        if (read != AudioRecord.ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION) {
            try {
                float tempHammingRes[] = null;
                hamming(bufferSize);

                Complex[] complexs = new Complex[bufferSize];
                Complex[] results = new Complex[bufferSize];
                for (int i = 0; i < bufferSize; ++i) {
                    data[i] /= 32767; 
                    tempHammingRes[i] = tempHammingRes[i] * data[i];
                    complexs[i]= new Complex(tempHammingRes[i], 0);
                }

                results = FFT.fft(complexs);

                double highScore = 0.0;
                int freq = 1;

                for (int line = 1; line < bufferSize; ++line) {
                    double magnitude = Math.log(results[line].abs() + 1) / Math.log(10.0)*20.0;
                    if (magnitude > highScore) {
                        highScore = magnitude;
                        freq = line;
                    }
                }

                double currentFrequence = ComputeFrequency(freq, bufferSize);

                Log.d(TAG, "highScore = " + highScore + " freq = " + currentFrequence);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Now, I have a question that in the code block II there will be obtained same frequency in the continuous FFT caculating interval. For example there are some logs outputed from the code blocks II:

highScore = 151.77662972416104 freq = 7999.5849609375   // first 8000

highScore = 146.33073029829455 freq = 7999.5849609375   // second 8000

highScore = 146.44411729898255 freq = 9000.87890625

highScore = 144.43481176938155 freq = 9000.87890625

highScore = 142.78046692784702 freq = 10002.1728515625

highScore = 141.91874938214298 freq = 10002.1728515625

highScore = 136.47269911015098 freq = 11003.466796875

highScore = 136.6873278405228 freq = 11003.466796875

I only generated one 8khz, but I get two sound frequency. I also decrease the duration of output tone or incrase the input buffersize of audio recorder. Unfortunately, it doesn't help what I want to do..

Is there anybody know whether I'm wrong or the output of fft is like this in nature?

Thanks very much for your any answer!

Comment: *"FFT calculating .. without any frequency leakage."*  I believe FFT is inherently 'leaky'.  I *think* you can decrease the effect by increasing the number of bands analyzed.

Comment: What is the nature of the audio signal that you are working with ? Is it noisy ? Are there components which change amplitude/frequency rapidly ?

Comment: I'm having a hard time following your writing, so I'm not sure exactly what your question is, but the general "how to track frequency using the FFT" has been asked many many times.

Comment: Thanks for your answers and sorry for my english and description, I will try to describe this question clearly.

Comment: @Paul R (Andrew Thompson, Bjorn Roche) can you help me to answer the question, I have described this question again. Please let me know if I haven't cleared the question. Thank you verymuch.

Comment: @Paul R, I generated the sound myself. It is't noisy.

Comment: @Bjorn Roche, thank you very much, I have described the question more clearly as possible as I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few potential problems here. I could be misreading your code, but I'll mention these things because they LOOK like problems:

1. Despite windowing, the FFT always has "side-lobes". You've selected the hamming window which is probably ideal for this purpose, but you *may* be witnessing sidelobes. You shouldn't be, but if something is happening between genTone and recordInBackground (eg, of you are playing the sound through a speaker and rerecording it), that *could* generate enough noise and distortion to occasionally make the sidelobe data as prominent as the primary data.
2. It looks like you are reading all the way through the FFT results. Only the first half of the FFT will contain relevant results, and the second half is a mirror image of the first half. Due to slight numerical errors, you could be finding results in the second half larger than the first half. This problem also suggests you may be calculating your frequencies wrong. I cover this here (and more!):[Frequency detection using fft aka pitch](http://blog.bjornroche.com/2012/07/frequency-detection-using-fft-aka-pitch.html)
3. You bit-reverse your data going out, but not coming in. Maybe that's fine depending on what you are doing, but just from this much code it's wrong. The FFT can "see through" that, but you've effectively created a **tremendous** amount of noise.

I also noticed you are trying to compute the log of the absolute value of results of your FFT. This will only serve to make your calculations take longer. For your purposes, magnitude = results[line].abs() is fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Bjorn Roche. What's I want to do is that emit specific frequency to indicate some character. Record the voice and retrieve the frequency from the original data stream using fft. Then decode the character from specific frequency. Just like chirp app in ios. I have finished to retrieve the specific frequency like what you write in your blog. But I don't know how to decide the voice frame size which will be used in fft caculating. Can you help me to indicate where am I wrong? Thank you!

Comment: The fft resolution is related to the window size. I cover this in the blog post as well.

Comment: hi,  @Bjorn Roche. I know what's the window size and the fft resolution. Well, thanks for your answer and I will think about it myself.

Comment: Then I'm not sure I understand your new question -- it sounds different from your original question and you and you may want to post a new one.

Answer (score 0):

The AudioRecorder is not in sync with your input signal. So it is very likely that the data blocks you get from it is splitting your tone into two parts. That's why you get two consecutive logs with the same frequency.