# Get frequency from guitar input in real time

Tags: c#, signal-processing, naudio

I'm trying to get input from plug-in guitar, get the frequency from it and check whether the users is playing the right note or not. Something like a guitar tuner (I'll need to do a guitar tuner as well).

My first question is, how can I get the frequency of guitar input in real time?

and is it possible to do something like :

```
if (frequency == noteCFrequency)
{
//print This is a C note!!
}
```

I'm now able to get input from the soundcard, record and playback the input sound already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must compute the FFT -Fast Fourier Transform- of a piece of signal and look for a peak. For kinds of FFT, window type, window size... you must read some documentation regarding signal processing. Anyway a 25 ms window is OK and use a Hamming window, for example. On the net there is lot of code for computing FFT. Good luck!

Comment: Can I have more precise direction? I'm stucked. :(
Maybe because I'm too new to this.. It's so hard to understand FFT..

Comment: Go Wikipedia and search Discrete Fourier Transform. FFT is the 'quick' version of DFT. DFT transforms a piece of signal from time domain to frequency domain. For example, a signal representen in a time axis from 0 ms to 25 ms can be transformed to a frequency domain signal between 0 and 2pi, whereas 0 corresponds to 0 Hz and 2pi corresponds to sr Hz, being sr the sampling rate of your signal (usually 44.100 Hz, depending on your configuration/audio driver). I'm sorry but there is lot of theory here so you must spend a couple of hours learning about this concepts. Do not hesitate to ask again.

Comment: can I have your facebook? I'd like to know more and I actually have a lot of questions.

Comment: Yes for sure, my username is 'perez.didac'.

Comment: Is there any easier version? something like this
http://pitchtracker.codeplex.com/documentation

I'm using NAudio to get the input, but I'm so sure the buffer thingy and I do not know who to implement this as well.. Any idea?

Comment: Hi Jeff. The first step is to get the audio stream, and, for processing, you need to use small pieces of signals, stationary signal chunks: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_process .

Stationary signal chunks, in audio, are those of about 25 ms. For example, an audio signal of 1000 Hz pitch is T = 1ms. Thus, in a 25 ms chunk you will have 25 periods which is good for computing FFT. A 100 Hz is 10 ms, and 10.000 Hz is 0.1 ms, 250 periods. 25 ms, sampling at 44.100 Hz is about 1102.5 samples, so, always process chunks of about 800 - 1500 samples.

Comment: do you mind to explain it in more practical way? As in show it with C# coding, and explain from the code. I'm using NAudio library for getting input from microphone and save it to a wav file, my problem is how can I get the frequency and show it at a label.

Comment: I'll try to explain it in a short way. First, as read the audio data, separate it into chunks of 1024 samples (perfect since 1024 is a power of 2 and FFT will work very well). After that, you can compute the fundamental frequency for each 1024-sample chunk. Just Google it, look for "c# FFT" and this function will return you the FFT of each chunk, that is an another chunk of signal but with real and imaginary part, this is a complex 1024-sample chunk. After this,  multiply the result by itself: |fft·fft|=||fft||^2 and look for the peak in this chunk (the highest sample).

Comment: The position (in the x axis) of the highest sample in your final result will correspond to the fundamental frequency. This is a very EASY approach of your problem, but there are lots of improvements to this: compute FFT of overlapped chunks, use a window before computing FFT, and so on...

Comment: Can you just tell me how to use FftPitchDetector.cs ?

Answer (score 1):

For an implementation of FFT in C# you can have a look [at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170394/fast-fourier-transform-in-c-sharp).
Whiel I think that you do not need to fully understand the FFT to use it, you should know about some basic limitations:

1. You always need a sample window. You may have a sliding window but the essence of being fast here is to take a chunk of signal and accept some error.
2. You have "buckets" of frequencies not exact ones. The result is something like "In the range 420Hz - 440Hz you have 30% of the signal". (The "width" of the buckets should be adjustable)
3. The window size must contain a number of samples that is a power of 2.
4. The window size must be at least two wavelengths of the longest wavelength you want to detect.
5. The highest frequency is given by the sampling rate. (You don't need to worry about this so much)
6. The more precise you want your frequencies separated, the longer shall your window be.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers don't really explain how to do this, they just kinda waive their arms. For example, you would have no idea from reading those answers that the output of an FFT is a set of complex numbers, and you wouldn't have any clue how to interpret them.

Moreover FFT is not even the best available method, although for your purposes it works fine and most people find it to be the most intuitive. Anyway, this question has been asked to death, so I'll just refer you to other questions on SO. Not all apply to C#, but you are going to need to understand the (non-trivial) concepts first. You can find an answer to your question by reading answers to these questions and following the links.

[frequency / pitch detection for dummies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553047/frequency-pitch-detection-for-dummies/11569383#11569383)

[Get the frequency of an audio file in every 1/4 seconds in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11844914/get-the-frequency-of-an-audio-file-in-every-1-4-seconds-in-android/11855208#11855208)

[How to detect sound frequency / pitch on an iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696773/how-to-detect-sound-frequency-pitch-on-an-iphone/11620063#11620063)

[How to calculate sound frequency in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12721254/how-to-calculate-sound-frequency-in-android/12749323#12749323)

[how to retrieve the different original frequency in each FFT caculating and without any frequency leakage in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12329880/how-to-retrieve-the-different-original-frequency-in-each-fft-caculating-and-with/12353877#12353877)